# What, if any, is an appropriate use for the [loops] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/loops/info) summary for [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) reads:

> Loops are a type of control flow structure in programming in which a series of statements may be executed repeatedly until some condition is met.

There is also a (rather unsatisfying, and grammatically incorrect) tag usage section, that reads:

> The tag [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops) can be used for programming related problems in implementing loops feature of any programming language.<sup>†</sup>

I frequently find questions with this tag on SO that fail into one of three categories:

1. Questions explicitly pertaining to "loop" control flow constructs; syntax, etc. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817904/syntax-error-in-pl-pgsql-for-loop), [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289026/syntax-for-a-single-line-bash-infinite-while-loop))
2. Questions explicitly pertaining to issues that directly involve logic / programming errors or questions related directly to loops. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814506/looping-through-variables-in-a-windows-form), [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811324/get-first-row-from-repeater-field-within-loop), [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801146/while-loop-inside-for-loop))
3. Questions about code that happens to contain loops, even though the root issue is unrelated to these constructs. These fall into two subcategories:

   1. Questions where the OP *thought* loop logic was the issue, but actually the real problem was more general ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824523/writing-to-csv-in-multiple-columns-inside-a-loop-java) - Real issue was lack of understanding of file truncate/append modes).
   2. Questions that have nothing to do with loops. ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22823926/how-to-call-a-file-pointer-in-a-function)).

With the current tag definition, only 1 and 2 categorically belong in that tag. 3.1 is a candidate for possible removal of tag, and the tag should most certainly be removed from 3.2.

As far as data organization goes this tag doesn't seem to do much -- most questions about loops specifically pertain to the language they are written in, "loops" are a very basic construct, and so a simple language tag without "loops" will generally be enough to get the attention of a capable answerer. It also seems unlikely that somebody would want to browse the tag looking for general interesting questions about anything that has to do with loops (to each his own, though...).

However, I suppose it is useful for SEO. Additionally, the tag is somewhat popular, having 155 followers (?) and ~20,000 questions at the time of this writing (otherwise, to be honest, I would have just made a burninate request).

**What is the intended goal of this tag? Could the tag wiki use some improvement, or is it correctly conveying the intended goal of the tag? Is this tag frequently misused and, if so, is there a way to reduce misuse?** It seems often misused to me, and fairly generic. I feel the tag wiki could use some polishing. I try to clean up "loops" tags when I see them if I am sure the question falls into category 3.2, but for the most part I'm unsure how to handle this tag, and am unsure when (and if) it should legitimately be used.

---

<sup>†</sup> To me, this actually almost reads like it should be used on questions related to language interpreter and compiler design; which is obviously not the intention. So this, I feel, could at least use some clean up -- I'm just not sure how it should be cleaned up.

Comment: I think we are better of without this tag. I don't think the tag has any function at all.

Comment: Lets get rid of the loops!

Comment: @devnull All The Loops! We shall never use a loop again to do anything! hahaha

Comment: Long live tail recursion! ;)

Comment: There are a lot of different sorts of loops out there—the do/while/for loops of Algol/Pascal/C/etc. are really only the beginning. Lisps and Schemes have their own sorts of looping constructs (notably the `do` form and the named `let`), and Haskell has looping constructs of various sorts scattered through its libraries.

Comment: @dfeuer do you mean [tag:loop] should be kept?

Comment: @Tshepang, I'm not sure. It's better than the [tag:methods] tag.

Comment: There are things common to loops but language independent, concepts like loop unrolling.

Comment: While posts are in my search: the loops tag is handy.  For example: if tags contain loops && I need loop information, then I shall read, else I shall continue.  
:P :)

Comment: [Tags like this are low-value and should be 'nuked' and blacklisted.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/304229/173497)