# Get rid of the [methods] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The well-populated [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods) tag doesn't seem to serve any purpose, as far as I can tell. In languages that have methods (as opposed to functions or the nearly indistinguishable procedures), methods are such a fundamental part of the language that the tag adds little to the language identification tag. Yes, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)+[methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods) or [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)+[methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods) gives an indication that the question likely comes from a rank beginner, but I don't see how it adds any other useful information. Tags like [virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-method) and [abstract-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract-methods) give a bit of information, but [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods) runs the gamut: how to write a method, why a method throws an error, how to call a method, why a method doesn't exist, etc. No one can be an expert at [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods), no one would be likely to want to answer questions about [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods), almost no one would want to avoid questions about [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods), and no one looking for help with [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/methods) would find the tag useful for searching.

Comment: [tag:loops] is another one (discussed [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251139/what-if-any-is-an-appropriate-use-for-the-loops-tag?rq=1)).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I'm not sure what I think about [tag:loops] in principle, but narrowing the scope of either tag enough to make it useful would entail a tremendous amount of work to weed out the questions to which it no longer applies.

Comment: Title should have been something like "All [methods] are useless".

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat [My, usually [tag:methods] are useless here?](http://xkcd.com/55/)

Comment: You forgot to include [tag:methods] in the second and third lines, you broke the pattern :(

Comment: Only 11,000 + questions with the tag.  You'd better get started.

Comment: I agree that "methods" seems a pointless tag - Loops however is much more specific: If a new programmer is trying to understand how loops work then that tag would help them narrow their search wouldn't it?

Comment: @MattCoubrough, the loops tag is better discussed in [its own meta thread](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251139/what-if-any-is-an-appropriate-use-for-the-loops-tag?rq=1) that Burhan Khalid already mentioned.