# Does the [max-length] tag fulfill any purpose?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are currently 10 posts tagged with [max-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/max-length). Personally, I don't see any point in it - how can anyone be an expert in maximum lengths? Is there any good reason to keep such a tag?

Related topics that seem to follow similar ideas:

- [Do we really need [max] and [min]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255631/do-we-really-need-max-and-min)
- [What, if any, is an appropriate use for the [loops] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251139/what-if-any-is-an-appropriate-use-for-the-loops-tag)
- [Get rid of the [methods] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258491/get-rid-of-the-methods-tag?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With only three non-deleted questions you can easily remove the tag yourself **if it makes no difference to the understanding of the question**.

When a tag is unused it's deleted.

There was really no need to bring this up on meta. If the tag had been used by hundreds or thousands of questions then that would have been a different matter and it certainly should have been discussed here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Guess there's still plenty to learn, even though I have been around for a while. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is now fixed by removing all tags from the questions.

When the script runs at 03:00 UTC the tag should be gone as well...

Comment: Thanks for that. Next time I'll know to do this myself. :-)