# [eventlistener], [event-listener] and [event-listeners] are all the same; make them one tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

We have these three tags with *identical* wikis and obviously overlapping lemmas:

- [eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener) (769 questions)
- [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) (104 questions)
- [event-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners) (252 questions).

I suggest to use only [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) (the hyphen makes the lemma more readable); either retag the other questions or make the tags synonyms of [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener).

Comment: I agree. [tag:event-listener] is clearer. But if you suggest that we use [tag:event-listener]... why did you very recently ask a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43470819/6850771) with [tag:eventlistener]?

Comment: Do note, however, is that [tag:event-listeners] could pertain to questions regarding the use of multiple event listeners used on the same element, e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17204913/6850771) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5411055/6850771) (top Google search result for 'multiple event listeners').

Comment: If we're going to clean this up, we should also be looking at [tag:listener].

Comment: @MDXF: Good point. Then the wiki should be fixed accordingly.

Comment: Is really any of this needed? I get there are event listeners on some languages... but isn't the language tag itself enough? Can't event listener experts find questions they like to answer?

Comment: @Braiam There are also [**`string`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) in every language, and we still have a tag for it. Why? Because it **brings clarity** to the question. I think knowing a question is about `event-listeners` just by the tags is an interesting point.

Comment: @Braiam: If you check how many different `*listener` tags we have, you will see that they are quite different lemmas. And anyway: That would be a different question.

Comment: @Mistalis you are barking to [the very wrong tree](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066)

Comment: What value does [tag:event-listener] add over [tag:events]? Isn't an event listener an implicit part of the [tag:events] programming construct?

Comment: @MDXF _Do note, however, is that event-listeners could pertain to questions regarding the use of multiple event listeners used on the same element_ -- Are you saying a separate tag should be required for those kinds of questions?

Comment: @ZevSpitz An event listener is attached to an object and listens on it. Multiple event listeners attached to the same object could be an entirely different concept. Thus, you tell me - is a question about an event listener the same as a question about attaching multiple event listeners to one object?

Comment: @MDXF _An event listener is attached to an object_ -- More precisely, an event listener is attached to an object's **events**. In my experience, an event listener is never attached directly to an arbitrary object, but rather an object has defined events to which one or more listeners can be attached. Isn't this implicit in the very name _**event** listener_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done now; sorry it took so long!

The following tag merges have been performed, and corresponding synonyms created:

- [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) ← [eventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eventlistener)
- [event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listener) ← [event-listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-listeners)