# Can programming questions involving math ever be on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I just came across this question:

[How to expand and compute log(a + b)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3974793)

It's closed, presumably because it's a question about math, which generally isn't on topic. But for this particular question, there is a very programming-related issue with solving it in the obvious way: it is very easy to hit underflow or overflow. (This isn't just a hypothetical; it's a well-known issue when implementing e.g. naive Bayes classifiers.)

**If the question were rewritten in terms of the under/overflow issue, e.g. something like this:**

> I am trying to calculate `log(a + b)` given `log(a)` and `log(b)`. The problem is, `log(a)` and `log(b)` are so negative that when I try to calculate `a` and `b` themselves, they underflow and I get `log(0)`, which is undefined.
>
> For `log(a * b)` and `log(a / b)`, this isn't a problem, since `log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b)` and `log(a / b) = log(a) - log(b)`. Is there a similar way to calculate `log(a + b)` without needing `a` and `b` themselves, avoiding the underflow?

**Would that be an acceptable question for Stack Overflow?** If not, what would be the more appropriate site?

(Part of the reason I bring this up is that there is a very programming-specific detail in the proper solution to this question: Most languages have a `log1p` function in their standard library that calculates `log(1 + x)`, meant to solve exactly the sort of issue above. And there is a correct way to use it in order to preserve the most precision. An answer on [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) would not include such programming details.)

Comment: Definitely, dealing with the underflow issue sounds very much like a programming problem. In contrast, it's not clear that [the question in its current state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974793/how-to-expand-and-compute-loga-b) has anything to do with programming, it seems like pure math to me, which isn't on-topic.

Comment: @CertainPerformance In that case, would it be appropriate for me to edit the original question into something like the above, and attempt to get it reopened? Or create a new question matching the above? This is an actual issue I faced that I couldn't find an answer to here. I eventually found the solution elsewhere, and it'd be nice to share it for the benefit of future programmers.

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP was asking about the underflow issue, so editing that old question wouldn't be appropriate - better to post your own.

Comment: The emphasis of the question has to be programming, not math. If that is the case, there is nothing against programming questions about math.

Comment: Let's exaggerate the example by swapping it out; if you're writing the control software for a rocket ship at NASA, you do not get a free pass to ask about rocket ships on Stack Overflow. Your question must still be about a programming problem and it'd be best if the question involves as little as possible about rocket ships.

Comment: "Can programming questions involving math ever be on topic?" <- Sure, why not. I've answered a bunch of them and probably asked one or two myself.

Comment: After all the feedback here, I posted a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65233445/) and an answer for it.

Comment: Let me give a counter example: prime numbers.  There's nothing more math-y than prime numbers, but there's no end of programming questions about them.  The last one I saw involved an interesting constraint, less than 1 bit of memory allowed per number tested.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or math.stackexchange.com. If you cannot find the answer here, might be a better option. It is really about whether this is mathematical theory or computer science theory. CS involves the programming. Math involves, well, the mathematical theory. It could get shady in those two when discussing numerical analysis topics like convergence.

Comment: IIUC all 3 answers here that say it is off-topic and all are upvoted. Yet other high-rep users re-opened the question a few hours after this was posted on Meta. I'd be interested to know their reasons. How does SO resolve such differences of opinion?

Comment: it seems an open/close war has kicked-off: I probably encouraged it :(

Comment: @dcorking "How does SO resolve such differences of opinion?" By consensus, discussion on meta, exhaustion of open/close votes and finally a moderator stepping in.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Of course, all programming boils down to math.

There, now that we've got the pretentious answer out of the way:

**Yes, if it's about *implementation* of the math.**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057836/labelpropagation-how-to-avoid-division-by-zero/52144825) is basically parallel to your question - I want to do calculation X, but I have over/underflow.  How do I solve it?  Needs math, but fundamentally an implementation question.

On the other hand, [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033237/numpy-raise-diagonalizable-square-matrix-to-infinite-power) is a tensor math question masquerading as an implementation question.  It's code copied from another answer, but they want to know how the math works.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968679/statistics-how-to-create-data-sample-of-specific-distribution) is just a (bad) statistics question with some code shoved in the middle of it.

Then there's iffy ones like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688112/spring-physics-applied-to-quaternions-using-python/44696087) which is mostly a quaternion calculus and numerical methods question, but is, at its core, about how to implement it all into a well-defined use-case.

Basically, if an answerer can answer the question without any code (and would likely sorely miss having `MathJax` like Stats and Math stacks have) then it's likely not on-topic for SO.  The original question (and its most upvoted answer) suffer from this.  The codeblocks are basically just equations that would be clearer as `MathJax`

Comment: How does programming, as in expressing computer instructions in code, boil down to math? I can see how it boils down to logic, but math is a distinct superset of logic just as programming is.

Comment: @Alex There's a reason they call it a *computer* - at the end of the day all it does is various forms of binary math.  Although I guess whether binary math is math or applied logic is a question for philosophy of science folks.

Comment: But the computer is not doing the programming, the computer is executing the resulting code. If someone is using a computer for graphic design, would you say that doing graphic design on a computer boils down to math? I don't see how that way of expressing it makes any useful sense.

Comment: That's why it's the pretentious answer.  It's technically true (and something mathematicians like to say about almost every field), but functionally meaningless.  It's a joke.

Comment: Haha, I didn't get that. I'm probably slightly damaged having to explain to people every now and then that no, just because I'm a programmer it doesn't mean that I'm good at math.

Comment: [It's math all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis).

Comment: All questions network-wide [are applied maths](https://xkcd.com/435/). 

Comment: @PeterMortensen Might want to repost that with the correct number (435). If you do I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 13):

> **Can programming questions involving math ever be on topic?**

Yes, and you've actually mentioned a reasons for that: Programming problems regarding the computation like under-, overflows, precision and so on. A question involving math could also be about language-specific syntax or design.

> **If the question were rewritten in terms of the under/overflow issue, e.g. something like this:** [...]

The question as it is right now doesn't state in any way that it's about a programming problem. So editting the question would differ from what the OP has actually asked and therefore would be invalid. I really like your suggested edit and I'd suggest you to post a new question with it.

> **Would that be an acceptable question for Stack Overflow?** If not, what would be the more appropriate site?

It would be. Anyways, I'd like to mention the sites where mathematics + programming is on-topic:

- Stack Overflow
- [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- (Some others, which are very specific.)

I don't want to explain when to post where exactly because there are the corresponding Help Centers for that and posts like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on).

So in conclusion: When such a question is not for [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) as it includes programming specific problems, then Stack Overflow is not the wrong place for it.

Comment: Pay attention before advertising another site, that the question is valid on this site too. I remember a question about drawing a circle passing by the points of a triangle, without any effort by the OP. OK to close it. But someone indicated that they voted to close it, because math.se was more appropriate. A primary-school math level question, with no effort, appropriate for math.se???

Comment: also [CrossValidated](stats.stackexchange.com) for statistical programming

Comment: @Damien Math.SE accepts [any level of maths](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827072/finding-an-equation-of-circle-which-passes-through-three-points?noredirect=1&lq=1), or so they say. The "no effort" is a different problem though.

Comment: @Andrew The "no effort" is not a totally different problem at math.se. There, there is obviously a tolerance for difficult and interesting problem, where it is admitted to stay stuck. I am following math.se from time to time. Until now, I have never seen a primary school question. Rectification: I just see your link. Effectively. Surprising

Answer (score 7):

My 2c:

The question **as stated** rather belongs on math.stackexchange.com than stackoverflow.com.

However, if the question is placed **in some context**, it would make perfect sense to ask here on stackoverflow.com:

For example, how to expand `log(a+b)`... :

- ...in ES2028 (because BigNum or automatic int→float conversion)
- ...to memoize partial computation (e.g. `log(a)`)
- ...to parallelise on a GPU (`log(a+b) for (a,b) in matrix`)

Comment: Your point of view on SO makes sense, but I disagree that this would be on-topic at Math.SE with its focus on computation. If SO isn't appropriate, I suspect the next best place would be Computational Science.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few problems with the OP question.

1. The question does not state the underflow and therefore looks more like a mathematical problem and is therefore [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).
2. The OP does not give a proper explaination as to why they need the expanded solution. This can make it harder for us as a community to fully understand the problem (see 1).
3. As there is no programming related problem stated in the question, this question would be more suited for [math stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Now let's look at your rewritten question.

The problem with this is since the OP did not originally mention the underflow problem (and has not in the comments at time of writing), the new question changes the problem and therefore can change the context and maybe the answers.

Besides that, I'd say your question is on-topic for stack overflow, but unless the OP changes the question to say that the underflow is the problem, they remain two unrelated questions.

Therefore this question should not replace the question asked by the OP.

Comment: I agree. People sometimes go to heroic lengths to redeem a question through edits, resulting in a question whose answers wouldn't necessarily help the OP (nor, often, even be understandable to them). If you feel there's the seed of a good question in there, just *start a new question* and link to it from the original question.

Comment: @Sneftel I guess people do that because there's a need for less questions but more valuable information, perhaps. Not that it's right, of course. Edits shouldn't deviate from the intention of the author.

Comment: @Sneftel I can tell you what was going through *my* head: Since the original question was on Stack Overflow, and this is a fairly common technique in certain fields (e.g. Bayesian classifiers), I assumed they must have been hitting the underflow issue and just didn't do a great job explaining the real issue. It's obvious now that this assumption was not mine to make.

Comment: This is not serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Discrete math is the *basis* of computer science. Questions about math are absolutely essential.

I specialize in factorization. There are a great number of people with a ton of questions relating to prime factors for a variety of very valid reasons. Factorization algorithms *definitely* fall in the category of math questions. Very deep math questions in fact.

This entire class of problems can't even be discussed if we aren't allowed to share questions related to number theory, combinatorics, or graph theory.

Comment: Nobody denies the importance of math. Here we are more interested in finding the best place for programming + math questions. There is probably some kind of transition where math questions better belong on the math or computer science part of this network. The general approach in the past has been that the scope of the single sites of the network overlap and that questions that fall into that overlapping region may be posted on any site where they are ontopic. This question here tries to find out, how big that overlap actually is. Maybe you have more concrete examples of questions that ...

Comment: ... would be heavily math oriented but should still be ontopic here because programming is also fundamental to them. We could learn something from the examples. The other answers here so far left me a bit unsatisfied. I feel like I still don't know exactly at which point math questions are on/offtopic here.

Comment: Can you add some *examples* of questions that you think are on-topic?

Comment: Yes. Go to you tube and search for Monty's Python Algorithm. Here's the underlying math: factor = gcd(n, f(x))

Answer (score -3):

**EXMAPLES**

1. There are lots of questions touching cryptography and associated mathematical problems, insofar YES. By expectation the answers reference the specialized community.
2. Formal verification of algorithms is about describing them by mathematical models and should anyway be on topic.

A real problem is, when you raise a large scale topic, which addresses multiple disciplines and no community wants to take responsibility for the content.

The agenda of StackOverflow is obviously to keep math formally out, as mathematical notations in LaTex style are not even supported: Creating simple things like super-script, sub-script or the table shape of a matrix with usual html-capabilities is a real torture.

Answer (score -4):

Seems like you've already answered your own question in its title:

> **involving** math

If the question involves using math **in the context of a software development problem**, it's on-topic. If it doesn't, it's off-topic.

The original question has nothing at all to do with programming; it's asking about logarithmic identities, which even the most cursory Google search will answer. Hence it's manifestly off-topic.

Now, knowledge of these identities might be relevant in e.g. embedded systems programming where many "intrinsics" that higher-level programmers take for granted, e.g. `log(a + b)`, are not available natively and have to be implemented by the programmer. Had the question been framed in that manner, it *may* have been on-topic.

Always remember the golden rule, [paraphrased from elsewhere](https://old.reddit.com/r/programming):

> If there is no code in your question, it probably doesn't belong here.

Comment: Golden rule? I don't think it's a golden rule. It may be your own opinion, which Is fine. Everyone is entitled to have an opinion, but stating it as a golden rule is just wrong, as it isn't a rule here. But I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Once you get to a certain level, code is something you do *after* you've answered all your questions.

Comment: One point of contention, "*which even the most cursory Google search will answer*" Just because you can find the answer to a question on google doesn't mean the question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: _If there is no code in your question, it probably doesn't belong here._  Utter nonsense!   It is well established here on Meta the absence of code, on it's own, is not a reason to close.  Many of the most 
interesting Q's don't contain code. 
 That said, it might be an indication of other problems