# Is the language-agnostic tag redundant?

Tags: discussion, tags

From the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info) for the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag:

> Use this tag for PROGRAMMING QUESTIONS that are independent of any particular programming language.

Not having any programming language tag on the question implicitly means that it is a language-agnostic question. For instance, every [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) or [data-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structure) question, which doesn't have any other language tag, is a language-agnostic question.

Comment: Related: [Should you add a language tag when your question is not too language specific?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403503/1364007)

Answer (score 7):

It is a helpful tag if I'm looking for questions to answer: I can search for questions that are tagged with a language I know *or* are language-agnostic. I can't easily search for *not having any programming language tag*.

Comment: This is the single most useful way to describe the usefulness of this tag. It's also worth adding that, while the [[tag:language-agnostic]] tag adds some non-zero amount of information about the post content (just like a language tag does), *not* having a tag gives actually *zero* information. What if they just forgot a language tag?