# "Do not use" recently added to [language-agnostic]

Tags: discussion, support, specific-edit, tag-excerpt

I noticed recently that the [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) tag got "DO NOT USE" [added to its excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5197182/5) on Jan. 5:

> DO NOT USE. Instead, use a tag that is related to the content in your question, e.g. [algorithm]

As far as I could tell, there wasn't a discussion about doing so, and instead this just seems to be a user adding it to the excerpt outright (as they have direct edit privileges).

This tag has previously garnered some discussion ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403871/is-the-language-agnostic-tag-redundant), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354935/is-language-agnostic-a-real-topic), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355295/clean-up-language-agnostic)), but never a formal burnination request (as far as I could find), nor talks of adding the above message to the tag.

May this edit be reverted?

<sup>A meta post seemed the best route for this, since I can't rollback a tag wiki edit, or even flag it for attention.</sup>

Comment: The tag has it's uses, so I agree that the edit should be reverted.

Comment: ...reverted?  How do you revert a tag edit?

Comment: @Makoto I assume Scratte means rolled back. I agree, this seems to be something that should only be done after discussion on Meta.

Comment: @cigien:  After now that I've actually *found* the option I don't think there's much *need* to discuss it too much further.  A bad edit should be reverted.  (Additionally I don't know why it took me so long to actually find the revert option for those edits...)

Comment: @Makoto Actually, I meant the original edit that added "Do Not Use" should not have been done without discussion :) I was going to roll it back myself after adding my last comment, but got distracted, so that's my bad. Thanks for taking the action.

Comment: While the edit does seem inappropriate, looking at the 1st page of questions with this tag, none seem to be relevant - some should have [algorithm] instead and some have [language-agnostic] together with a language tag?! (E.g. [c++], [java]). I suspect this tag should be removed.

Answer (score 47):

I see both sides.

On the one hand, there are some reasonable questions which are language agnostic, which talk and discuss more specific programming things (e.g. tail recursion, floating-point math, etc).

On the other hand, the tag has started to get abused for those folks who want an algorithm when [algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm) is perfectly suitable for their usages.

Adding "do not use" doesn't fix this (nor will it ever); we just need to start removing the usages of [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) when it doesn't apply.

Comment: *"Adding "do not use" doesn't fix this (nor will it ever)"* - indeed. One of the many examples: [[tag:web]] - 42k questions...

Comment: Also, moving the usage section to the top before the large list of books might help those poor souls who actually read tag wikis. As for the rest, I think a "Do not use for algorithm questions (use [algorithm] instead)" - as a tamer version of the edit - can be added to the excerpt (if there will be a consensus that such a note will not do more harm than good).

Comment: I still don't get the difference, because the tag wiki of `language-agnostic` contains so many references to algorithm. Many of the books are named _... Algorithms ..._. It even suggests to add the `algorithm` tag along with `language-agnostic`.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer, the difference, as I see it, is that while algorithms are language-agnostic, but not all language-agnostic concepts are algorithms (granted, a separate issue is whether such a blanket tag is justified - it looks meta-ish). The fact that its wiki happens to contain a lot of info on algorithms does not make a case against the tag per se.

Comment: Most such general algorithm questions should probably be asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com/. "Algorithm" is a horrible tag, why not add "programming" and "code" tags too then?

Comment: @Lundin "Programming" and "coding" describe almost everything on Stack Overflow. "Algorithm" does not. I do not understand the obsession with making sure that every question has exactly one suitable site. There are always going to be edge cases.

On the topic of algorithms in particular, I write differently for Stack Overflow than I do for CS, because they're different audiences (the most salient difference being comfort with CS theory).

Comment: I had forgotten this tag exists, but if I had remembered there's a few places where I would have used it where algorithm would not have applied.

Comment: Many questions tagged with [tag:algorithm] are very much language-specific and there's no shortage of questions that are either just about some general bug or error with an algorithm (which is related to algorithms in the same way code containing lists is about [tag:list]) or something really stretching the definition of "algorithm" (or at least using the strict definition, where every bit of code is an algorithm). There needs to be another tag as well for non-language-specific algorithm questions, although that tag is probably [tag:pseudocode] (combined with [tag:algorithm]).

Answer (score 19):

Courtesy of [@Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto), the edit [was reverted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5197182/6), and no further action is needed.

<sub>(Except, maybe, some overdue cleanup of both the tag's [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic?sort=newest) and [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/language-agnostic/info).)</sub>

Comment: Not sure about no further action needed. It can actually be an interesting community discussion whether this tag should exist or not. Although I doubt some action will be taken because of its antiquity and amount of questions...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I think there are some very clear cases where it was appropriate to use -- see f/e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true/26337004