# Any last [word]s?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

This tag needs to die as its very ambigous, and vague.

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

This tag doesn't help to describe the question in any way. It doesn't give us any information about the real content of the question, looking at it from the home page. It can apply to many (all?) languages and be a part of many frameworks/tools/etc...

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Nope. It could be a relevant tag on https://english.stackexchange.com/ but doesn't have any relevance in programming.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Nope, having a post tagged with [word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word) doesn't add any meaningful info whatsoever.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Different people could use it is different context often describable better with a more specific tag. More often than not, its being misused against the wiki description for all sorts of context.

Comment: *"Nope. It could be a relevant tag on https://english.stackexchange.com/ but doesn't have any relevance in programming."* - Word size can absolutely have relevance in programming..., the tag description even describes the correctly relevant type of word.

Comment: It could be on-topic if it's about this ['word'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)), but I agree it's too ambiguous.

Comment: Could you please follow the required bunination request points and add the current usage and numbers also. From your given notices, I'd partly support the bunination request too. Could be though that it just needs an adaption in the tag-wki description.

Comment: I feel like it is relevant, the tag description shows that. The name is a tad bit ambiguous though. Maybe rename it to something like [word-size]?

Comment: I'm in favor of disassociation to clarify the use cases. `word` on its own is pretty meaningless. Just renaming it probably won't work - there's several different meanings of word that apply to programming.

Comment: It's quite ambiguous, especially since Microsoft also decided to have a `WORD` data type that's always 16 bit, so even when talking about integer size there's confusion. However, it's certainly on-topic, so disambiguation is the proper thing to do, not burnination, imo.

Comment: From a quick pass on the first page of the 2k+ questions tagged `word`, the use-cases vary between: The Microsoft Word program/related file formats ; A text word in the context of strings ; A word in the context of memory access (16/32 bits). The latter actually fits the wiki description

Comment: It's clearly on-topic, but look at some of the recent posts. We have words (language construct), Word (Microsoft), WORD (data type), word (Vi/Vim text object), functions containing the literal "word", converting words to numbers, and word replacing in iterm - and that's just the first page (size = 50).

Comment: Folks, please, let's stop trying to burninate concepts on the pretence of misuse (see attempts: array, element, triggers, list, and others [all declined or gone stale after backlash]). This is a scorched earth tactic - just because the people who can't be bothered to read half a sentence when slapping what they believe to be hashtags (thanks Twitter!) doesn't mean we should nuke tags. We can't do anything with people tagging Microsoft Word questions [word]. If you care about the tag - help it and retag MS Word questions to the tag they belong to: [ms-word]

Comment: "It can apply to many (all?) languages" - this is *absolutely fine*. The concept *does not need to be applicable in one language or framework only*. There are universal and basic concepts. "It could be a relevant tag" on English SE it would mean exactly what the site is about: a linguistics concept. On SO it means what it usually means - a unit of data.

Comment: If there is a need to clarify meaning, let's do it, but please, *stop burning concepts*. Sorry for the rant, I couldn't take it anymore. That out of the way, I can only second @ErikA here - disambiguation and editing effort may be due, let's discuss the possibilities and caveats.

Comment: @OlegValter all true. What I can't take anymore is that you mistook the commentbox for the answerbox ....

Comment: @OlegValter "let's stop trying to burninate concepts on the pretence of misuse" lets stop trying to keep misused tags on the pretense that they are used as concept. Remember, tags needs to demonstrate they are useful first, rather than making sense in the abstract. Having a tag just for having a tag is not useful.

Comment: @rene - yeah, sorry, I am just not sure if that's enough for the answer, to be honest. I am thinking of a more level-headed commentary that I hope I can confidently post as an answer.

Comment: @Braiam - I know your stance on abstract tags and, unfortunately, our positions on the matter are simply irreconcilable. I prefer the "not guilty unless proven otherwise" approach to dealing with content.

Comment: @OlegValter I was thinking of posting an answer but your comments basically cover what I dreamed up.

Comment: @OlegValter oh really? [You know my stance?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300700/792066)

Comment: @Braiam - I don't want to get confrontational. It is just that we clashed on several instances of the same problem, so I am pretty confident about where our positions on the matter differ, that's all there is to my comment. I also strongly disagree with the "prove your worth or die" approach to tags (if I somehow misread the comment you made, I do apologize in advance)

Comment: @OlegValter is not even "prove your worth or die". It's a three step process: does this tag describe something that is withing the scope of this site, it's used correctly and it's curated regularly by members of the community. So, yes, you have a misrepresentation of what is my stance.

Comment: @Braiam - I am really unsure what that means then: "tags needs to demonstrate they are useful first". In my point of view, the onus is always on the accuser: they need to provide evidence that the tag is actively harmful and requires burnination, not the other way around. Re: within the scope - exactly. As with [arrays] and [triggers], [word] is an on-topic programming concept. Does the tag need some love? Sure. Does it need to be disambiguated? Probably. But not initiate a burnination request every time a tag designating a concept is misused by clueless users.

Comment: @OlegValter useful for the site via the three pronged approach: a off topic tag isn't useful, it generates off topic content; a tag not used correctly isn't useful, content isn't properly categorized; a tag that is not curated isn't useful, quality isn't assured for content categorized into it. Usefulness is a conjugation of different aspects and has to fulfill them all.

Comment: @Braiam - curation of a tag is not so much a problem of the tag, but of us, curators. There is also a difference between a tag generating off-topic content as it is inherently off-topic and because it is misused. I have no quarrel with burning the former, but strongly against doing that to the latter. This is the crux of my frustration with *some* of the burnination requests (in no thanks to the ambiguously defined process). Conjure a punny title, throw in a couple of examples of misuse, say that different *contexts* make a word mean different things - boom, burnination request.

Comment: @OlegValter well, it's still a problem. There it is. Also, are you sure that you want a tag that only creates more work for the rest of us? And how is that useful?

Comment: @OlegValter if you think the tag is not useful in its current form and needs more specificity, then that itself is the proof that that tag in itself isn't adding any value. I'm all for specific tags but these generic tags' existance is just asking for misuse.

Comment: @MohdAbdulMujib - I never said anything like that. The fact that there is a problem does not mean we need to jump to burnination. This is a destructive action where one can disambiguate or just clean up. I don't see anything wrong with tags about concepts - they are inherently on-topic and that's already *enough* to keep them around. Misuse is a treatable problem in most cases, but not after you decapitated the patient.

Comment: see Tomerikoo's answer below? That's a constructive approach to the problem. Burnination, however, is destructive in nature and should be wielded with care. I strongly disagree with any approach that leads to burning tags because of misuse, not because they are off-topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a slight problem with your request because the answer to the second question is not correct. The concept described in the tag (backed by its tag wiki) is on-topic and programming related. Quoting it:

> A word is the amount of data that a processor can fit in its general-purpose registers -- effectively the amount of data the processor can handle "at once".

Now, the main problem with this tag is not that it's off-topic, rather that it's being misused (like almost all tags?). Just to get a general idea<sup>1</sup>:

- There are currently **86** questions also tagged [`x86`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+x86), [`mips`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+mips), [`assembly`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+assembly), [`memory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+memory), [`byte`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+byte) or [`char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+char) which are most likely on-topic (or at least have the best chances).
- <del>There are <del>**13**</del> **2** questions tagged [`wordpress`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+wordpress) which were tagged with `word` probably with no special reason.</del>
- There are **112** questions also tagged [`excel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+excel), [`vba`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+vba), [`office-js`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+office-js), [`ms-word`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+ms-word), [`docx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+docx), [`python-docx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+python-docx) which relate to the Microsoft related program and file types.
- The rest are basically tagged with a whole plethora of languages and mostly relate to `word` in the linguistic meaning as in word in text:

  - 201 questions tagged with [`string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+string)
  - 119 questions tagged with [`regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+regex)
  - 63 questions tagged with [`text`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+text)
  - 31 questions tagged with [`frequency`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/word+frequency)
  - and so on...

So, in conclusion, I believe that the right course of action here is clean-up and rename. The clean-up might require a wide effort by the community to cover the different sub-communities of all the languages it touches. Generally speaking:

- memory-related questions should keep the tag as per its usage guidance.
- Microsoft-related questions should be re-tagged with [ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-word).
- linguistic-related questions simply shouldn't have it. If the question is about finding a word in a string - the language tag combined with `string` is probably enough. The fact that you're looking for a word is just a detail in the question's body.

Once cleaned, the tag should be renamed to something less ambiguous with its usage guidance, Maybe `word-size`, `word-memory-size`, `memory-word` etc.

---

<sup>1. DISCLAIMER: the following numbers are pure estimates based on [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1398286/cross-tag-tag-usage-breakdown?tagname=word) just to get the general idea.</sup>

Comment: I propose to rename to [word-unit] - a bit clunky, but unmistakeable. Not adamant about the suggestion at all, though - just an idea.

Comment: I think most of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=word+frequency+%5Bword%5D) could be retagged to [[tag:word-frequency]]

Comment: In [Forth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29), [“word” means a defined command](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/7-signed-double-length-numbers/) (similar to function/subroutine/method in other languages). (16-bit numbers on the stack go by the name "cells" to avoid confusion with "words".)

Comment: @PeterMortensen - only [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bforth%5D+%5Bword%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3) to look at thankfully :) Since I am not an SME, can you take a look?

Comment: @OlegValter edited out. According to Peter's explanation (I wasn't even aware of the existence of Forth), it clearly doesn't use word as described in the wiki

Comment: @Tomerikoo - thanks! I also oblivioned the [tag:docs] (so both [docx], [python-docx] can be safely crossed out off the list) - same problem, people are just too used to the "Word" shortcut... Re: Forth - it came up a couple of times on my radar, but it is too esoteric to my tastes to even try :(